# How do you delimit mulitiple Neo4j cypher queries in a script file?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have programmatically generated a bunch of cypher queries to populate a Neo4j database. I wanted to use the drag and drop feature of the Database access page at port 7474 to load the statements.  I can execute the individual statements just fine.  But the statements in aggregate (delimited with ';') produce a syntax error.

Comment: Unfortunately the neo4j browser does not yet support multiple statements.

Comment: This is really frustrating when building scripts

Answer (score 5):

You can use the neo4j-shell (Neo4jShell.bat) to run multiple statements separated by `;`

The shell lives in the `bin` directory of your neo4j-server, but is also available under `localhost:7474/webadmin/#/console/`.

By default it connects to a running server but you can also specify a database directory:

```
bin/neo4j-shell -path test.db [-config conf/neo4j.properties] [-file import.cql]
```

And you can pass along a file to be read and executed (e.g. for import).

On Unix Systems you can also pipe to the shell:

```
cat import.cql | bin/neo4j-shell -path test.db
```

See [Rik's Blog](http://blog.bruggen.com?view=sidebar) for more fun with the shell, there is also http://www.neo4j.org/develop/shell